# SELECT нескольких таблиц из LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы users и phones

В users есть id и username
В phones есть id, user_id, phone

Соотношение Многие к одному. Как составить результирующую таблицу вида:
id, username, phone1, phone2, phone3 и так далее.
Количество номеров пользователя не ограничено. Суть вопроса в том, Как в SELECT указать значения из LEFT JOIN другой таблицы? 
Оффтоп: 3 дня не могу решить эту беду. набросайте хоть примерный SQL запрос

Comment: Если вы хотите phone1, 2, 3 в виде отдельных полей - то никак. Возвращаемая из запроса таблица строго прямоугольная, количество колонок во всех строках одинаково и задано в самом запросе. Если устроит список через запятую, можете посмотреть в сторону group_concat (для MySQL) или ее аналогов в других СУБД

Comment: Как раз и нужна строго прямоугольная таблица, что бы результаты JEFT JOINа были в виде столбцов. это можно сделать вручную, если заведомо знаешь сколько будет полей и для каждого джойна в SELECT указывать его. Грубо говоря вопрос в том, есть ли в SQL что то на подобии foreach?

Comment: Количество столбцов результата в любом случае должно быть строго задано в самом запросе. иначе никак. динамически количество столбцов в зависимости от данных меняться не может. В части SQL для таких вещей есть pivot. но вы не указали СУБД так что сказать что то конкретное невозможно. Если pivot нет, то его делают либо кучей join, либо группируя и выводя нужные значения в нужные поля с помощью `max(case when field1='X' then field2 end)`